# Stop build from Android Studio 2.2 sync and build automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was working on android studio 1.4, there clicking on gradle sync icon ("Sync Project with gradle files") on the top middle , performed only sync for gradle scripts, no build.
Now in Android Studio 2.2, clicking on gradle sync perform sync and build both.
Is there a way to stop AS from doing that, no build, only sync.

Comment: Reason for that please that you only need sync ?

Comment: Our codebase is really big, involving a lot of projects scattered at many places. We need android studio functionalities on a smaller subset of those projects that any dev is interested to work upon. We have our own build process in place to build stuff via gradle, hence we dont need AS build. Only sync to verify correctness of scripts and make intellisense etc working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it myself, we have to tick the "skip source generation.." in gradle experimental settings. For my purpose I have given the value 0 in module numbers.

[image]